# Infopath access issue

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am trying to open my info path form(xsn) which is located in my company sharepoint website in my personal computer(out of my company network). when I tried to open in infopath I am getting this error.

InfoPath
Your user name cannot be verified because the form's security settings do not permit it.
Error occurred during a call to property or method 'get-UserName'.

Comment: Pity I say, open it from your work PC where your user name is verified, then save as locally with removed security.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open XSN form template on server (also to note that Infopath XSN template is used to generate Infopath data forms or Infopath webparts), since it is a packed archive of many files, you can only download it to local machine and open it in Design mode in Infopath Designer (by right-clicking on the .XSN file > choosing Design option or opening Infopath Designer and then xsn template). Also, you should have Infpath, as part of MS Office suite, installed locally.

Also, if you downloaded XSN template to your local computer, double-clicking on it really results in attempt to generate an Infopath .XML data form and to open it in Infopath Filler. This will obviously fail, if there are (remote, for example, on sharepoint server) data connection/sources to which you local user does not have permissions (and this also the case when your Infopath template is web enabled = enabled for running in browser throigh Sharepoint server Infopath Form Services). You should digitally sign and change the template's **Security and Trust** (< Form Options < Info < File on ribbon of Infopath Designer) to **Full Trust** in order to preview it in Filler (that is, to generate on the basis of юЧЫТ template an Infopath data form - which is an Infopath .XML data form, in case of sharepoint libraries, and open it in Infopath Filler, locally).

This is for template published to a sharepoint (document oк form) library. Conceptually, it is all the same is In case of Sharepoint List Form, taking into account that its .XSN template is directly connected to underlying sharepoint list and there are no (separate) Infopath XML data forms.